# Flutter how to show/hide container in specing listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing my data in ListView.builder issue is i need to show/Hide widget in specific list but its applying on all list.

My code

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('show');
              setState(() {
                showQty = !showQty;
              });
            },
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Always'),
                showQty ? Text('onClick') : Container()
              ],
            ),
          );
   })
```

You can see I have 2 Text. Second Text I am showing when showQty is true its working fine but issue is its changing on all itemBuilder I need to show only on which item its clicking right now its applying on all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are applying click to all the items of list view. For implementing collapse and show on click you have apply bool to the specific index of list. Try as follows

```
  List<bool> showQty=[];



@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      showQty.add(false);
    }
  }

    void showHide(int i){
     setState((){
         showQty[i]=!showQty[i];
      });
    }

ListView.builder(
    itemCount: data.length,
    shrinkWrap:true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('show');
         showHide( index);
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Always'),
            showQty[index] ? Text('onClick') : Container()
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
)
```

Comment: But you define false 3 time I just give example of itemCount is 3 if itemCount is something length like     itemCount:  data.length then ?

Answer (score -1):

For show and hide widget you can use `Visibility` widget.
For more info about [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)
Hopefully can help you.